# Convert ARMA(p,q) to MA$(\infty)$ and find ACF

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, acf-pacf, moving-average-model

$Xt-0.4X_t+0.03X_{t-2}=Zt-0.4Z_{t-1}$
This process is causal and invertible.

For the $MA(\infty)$ representation, I wrote it as $X_t=\frac{1-0.4B}{1-0.4B+0.03B^2}Z_t$,
where $\psi(B)=\frac{1-0.4B}{1-0.4B+0.03B^2}$.

So, $X_t = \psi(B)Z_t=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\:\psi _i\:Z_{t-i}$

Now, I want to find the acf, this is where I get stuck.

For MA($\infty$) model, have that $\gamma_X(h)=\sigma^2\sum _{i=0}^{\infty }\:\psi _i\psi_{i+|h|}$

I'm not quite sure how to compute the acvf or the acf here, because I'm not sure how exactly I get the values for each $\psi_i$.

Comment: You need to express $\psi$ as a power series to read off $\psi_i$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I'm trying to follow the method from the Brockwell and Davis book: Intro to Time series and Forecasting, chapter 3 (3.1,3.2): http://home.iitj.ac.in/~parmod/document/introduction%20time%20series.pdf
I don't think they used a power series to solve it out, but would it be easier to do it that way?